# jq with regex in curl output

Tags: sed, jq

I have a below JSON

```
{
    "router": {
        "node_id": "ip-1-2-3-4",
        "state": "HEALTHY",
        "message": "OK"
    },
    "services": [
        {
            "service_id": "test@1234",
            "state": "HEALTHY",
            "message": "OK"
        },
        {
            "service_id": "something@45678",
            "state": "NOT HEALTHY",
            "message": "OK"
        }
```

I want to get the state, i can get that for first part of json but not for the rest

working:

```
curl -sk https://example/test | jq -r .router.state
```

1. How can i get the `state` for rest of the JSON under `services` only if it matches `"service_id": "test@*"`

`curl -sk https://example/test | jq -r .services.state` doesn't seems to work

2. How can i add regex to above command to match service_id value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.services[] | select(.service_id | test("test@*")).state
```

Will output `.state` where `service_id` matches the `test@*` regex.

If no matches are found, nothing is returned.

[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/APyisN59PD7)

Comment: Note that `test("test@*")` would also match `test1234` and `sometesting@45678`. The regex notation was asked for only in the second question, while the example given in the first one seemed to be some kind of globbing pattern (at least to me, maybe also abetted by the sample data given). This assumption, however, would translate it to something rather along the lines of `test("^test@.*")`.